# array instead of vector of vector, push_back() of elements. c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, dynamic-arrays, push-back

I use approach of **vector of vector** and would like to change it into **array** for performance reasons. However I failed at trying to understand, how can I use array (dynamic) and push data in the end of the array, if I do not know how many data are being read during my while loop. Here snippet below. Can you please explain how to perform it on array, as **push_back()** is only for vector? Would be so much grateful.

```
std::vector<vector<double>> v1;
while (1)
{
    ..../* some code, break condition aswell*/
    vector<double> tmp;
    while ( .../*new data available*/ ) 
    {
        ...
        tmp.push_back(data);
    } 
    v1.push_back(tmp);
}
```

Comment: `std::array`, native arrays or dynamic memory management? If you're going to use `push_back` you should stick to vectors.

Comment: I edited so that my question unambiguous. I want idea how to use array where I cannot have push_back()

Comment: Short answer: You can't.
Long answer: You can, by using a dynamically allocated array and resizing it as needed. But why would you want to do that, if `std::vector` does just that automatically?

Comment: I put in my question that I tend in direction of dynamic array, but am not sure how. And I meant, for performance reasons.

Comment: Well, yes, but a `std::vector` basically _is_ a dynamic array, and I am mystified about what performance gains you are hoping to get by doing manually what `std::vector` does automatically. I'll place any bet that you will in fact end up with _worse_ performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::vector<T>` **is** a dynamic array. What might speed up your code is this:

```
std::vector<vector<double>> v1;
while (1)
{
    ..../* some code, break condition aswell*/
    v1.push_back(vector<double>());
    while ( .../*new data available*/ ) 
    {
        ...
        v1.back().push_back(data);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try. What about vector of vectors, I saw opinions that this lowers performance. Especially when I use it as argument (reference) in other function calls?

Comment: Don't believe everything you read when it comes to performance ;-).
`std::vector` is really basically just a convenient wrapper for a dynamic array, with similar performance characteristics. And most of the time, STL containers are smarter than you when it comes to memory management :-). What you really SHOULD avoid is passing around vectors by value rather than as (const) references. That will really have a negative impact on performance.

Comment: @beginh That's wrong, it doesn't lower the performance when used via reference. Using references works in constant time.

Comment: sounds reasonable and since I never measured performance drop on my own, I follow your hints :-)

Comment: @Asfdlol have you tried whether **v1.push_back(vector<double>());** works? because i get 'illegal use of this type as an expression'

Answer (score 2):

If all the inner vectors are always going to be the same size, you probably don't want a vector of vectors but you can still use it.

The inefficiency can come from having to maintain a contiguous buffer and move objects around. If you have a lot of data that you are trying to store in memory you could use `std::deque` instead although in your case not all the data will be contiguous, just within each inner vector and the other vector itself.

If you know the size of the data in the inner vectors before you start doing `push_back` you can optimise with a `reserve()`.

Your slowness, assuming there is any, could be caused by poor algorithms and if you are accessing a lot of data in memory then cache misses. The latter of these is a complex topic but can lead to big improvements in performance.